Deploy a new version of a node app so new users can use the new version. with wild card subdomain in nginx
My main goal is to have new users use a new version of a node app and have the old users use the existing version(which will be an old version)
I use node js
I use Pm2 on Linux
A wild card server block with Nginx
 server{

    root /var/www/html;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx - debian.html;
    server_name *.example.com example.com www.example.com;
    location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
....
}

My node app  listens to port 8090.
The current version is on my "master" branch.
My new version is on a branch called “newBranch”.
I guess I want the new users to use the “newBranch” and the old users to use the “master branch”
I have low confidence in how to do the below strategy. So If you can help with commands that would be great.
I was thinking of adding a new remote to the "newBranch" to a repo that doesn’t exist yet. So somehow I will put only that branch on the remote. 
In the new branch, I will put a different port (8091) and spin up a new PM2.(Not sure if that will impact my server with CPU usage type of stuff)
Even if I get that done I don’t know how to handle the wild card in the Nginx file. How will I get it to point to 8091.
What better strategy is there and if this strategy is OK can you help with commands to use.
Just to be clear- The old users have a subdomain and I want them to keep the subdomain. New users should also get subdomains.
Maybe there's a way to tell Nginx all the old subdomains (like from an array) to serve from 8090 and the new subs to 8091?

Try this
// Test "newBranch" 
server{

    root /var/www/new-branch; // Folder for your newBranch

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx - debian.html;
    server_name new-branch.example.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8091;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

....
}


// default main
server{

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx - debian.html;
    server_name *.example.com example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    
....
}



How does this take into consideration the wildcard? I don't see how  server_name new-branch.example.com; will allow the new random subdomains to be created

in this case see with Herroku they can generate dynamic subdomain related to a gib branch

I'm also gonna say that root /var/www/html; just has the default html nginx file. So I don't use the "root" directive. I will keep question open. Not sure if I should start messing around with "root". And I'm not using Heroku
